# @Conditional configuration - Spring cannot find my beans

Tags: spring

I have an interface and two classes which implements in interface:

```
public interface Connector {
    void connect();
}

public class ConnectorOne implements Connector {
    @Override
    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("connector one");
    }
}

public class ConnectorTwo implements Connector {
    @Override
    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("connector two");
    }
}
```

I have a constroller in which I need to inject the instance of one of my classes:

```
@Controller
public class ConnectorController {

    public ConnectorController(Connector connector) {
        connector.connect();
    }
}
```

To decide which of the classes to use I am using environment variables:

```
public class ConnectorOneCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        String connectorType = System.getProperty("connector");
        return (connectorType != null && connectorType.equalsIgnoreCase("one"));
    }
}

public class ConnectorTwoCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        String connectorType = System.getProperty("connector");
        return (connectorType != null && connectorType.equalsIgnoreCase("two"));
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConnectorConfig {

    @Bean
    @Conditional(ConnectorOneCondition.class)
    public Connector getConnectorOne() {
        return new ConnectorOne();
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(ConnectorTwoCondition.class)
    public Connector getConnectorTwo() {
        return new ConnectorTwo();
    }
}
```

But when I start the application I get the message:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in guru.springframework.controllers.ConnectorController required a bean of type 'guru.springframework.services.Connector' that could not be found.

Why Spring cannot find two beans in the `ConnectorConfig` class ? And how can I fix it ?

Comment: You're not using any envisonment variable. You're using a system property. So if you haven' defined any matching system property, you have no Connector bean defined. Hzve you used your debugger to see what your conditions return?

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks. It helps me.